# How to hide stroke after dropping in to container

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a question regarding highlighting the image.When I click on image the stroke styles has to be visible and when i move the cursor apart of image then Stroke styles has to be invisible.
[I used this code as reference](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/)
In this example can u please worked out and I can hide the anchors but I cannot hide the stroke.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set the stroke color as transparent when not needed.

```
    var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
      stroke: 'transparent',
      ...

    anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
      this.setStroke('#666');
      ...

    anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
      this.setStroke('transparent');
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i can do it for anchors but i want stroke effect for image(borders of image) @bighostkim